# Python: Convert a string to its binary representation

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, binary-data, shellcode

I use Python 2.7.X.
I have a **text file** with the following content:

```
\xe87\x00\x10LOL
```

Note that this is the text itself, and not its binary representation (meaning the first char is '\\', not 0xe8)
When I read it (as binary), I get:

```
a = "\\\\xe87\\\\x00\\\\x10LOL"
```

because it is a text file.

I want to convert it to a binary form, meaning I want to get a file which begins with the characters
0xe8, 0x37, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4c, 0x4f, 0x4c.
(Note that 0x4c == 'L', 0x4f == 'O').

How do I do that?
Tried all sorts of solutions like hexlify\unhexlify, int(c, 16), but it seems like I'm missing something.
Also note that the length of the file varies, so struct.pack is less preferred.

Comment: You don't really want to read the character `"7"` as `0x07`, do you?

Comment: Which Python version do you use?

Comment: @TimPietzcker, you're right. I fixed it to 0x37 (== '7')

Comment: @falsetru, Python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`string-escape` or `unicode-escape` encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

```
>>> content = r'\xe87\x00\x10LOL'
>>> print content
\xe87\x00\x10LOL
>>> content
'\\xe87\\x00\\x10LOL'
>>> content.decode('string-escape')
'\xe87\x00\x10LOL'
>>> map(hex, map(ord, content.decode('string-escape')))
['0xe8', '0x37', '0x0', '0x10', '0x4c', '0x4f', '0x4c']

>>> bytes(map(ord, content.decode('string-escape')))
'[232, 55, 0, 16, 76, 79, 76]'

>>> bytearray(map(ord, content.decode('string-escape')))
bytearray(b'\xe87\x00\x10LOL')
```

Comment: This works almost out of the box. Had to remove the outer map, and replace it with a bytearray: `bytearray(map(ord, content.decode('string-escape')))`. Great answer, I didn't know that decoding.

Comment: @Sammy, Thank you for the feedback. I updated the answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
In [26]: a = r"\xe87\x00\x10LOL"

In [27]: b = ast.literal_eval("'" + a + "'")

In [28]: open("test.dat", "w").write(b)

In [29]: 
[1]+  Stopped                 ipython
$ xxd test.dat
0000000: e837 0010 4c4f 4c                        .7..LOL
```

(There are probably better tools than `literal_eval`, but that's the first that came to mind at this early hour in the morning.)

Answer (score 0):

`"".join([chr(int(i,16)) for i in data.split("\\x") if i])`

Comment: That shouldn't work, since not all chars in the original string begin with "\\x" (note the '7' in my example).